# Auto updated weekly - Excel

Tags: worksheet-function

I use a spreadsheet that has to be updated weekly and I want the date to change every week automatically.  How do I set it up?  ***THIS IS A SHARED FILE***

Comment: When you say shared - do you just mean on a network share where multiple people can open it?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the `=TODAY()` function (for the current date)

This will evaluate every time the spreadsheet is opened and update it to today's date.

However you might just want the date of the beginning of the week in there, for the whole week. You could do this as follows:

> =TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1

This will give you the date for the Monday of the current week **for the duration of that week**.
When you open it next week, it will put the date of the Monday of that week (all week)

Comment: Would be good to have a reason for the downvote. Does this answer not work? Does it not answer the question? As far as I can tell this does exactly what the OP wants, so if anyone has an issue with this answer please state what the problem is, so that it can be fixed. (Or post your own answer)